# How do i replace values of a list when found in the dictionary with its key? python

Tags: python

so im building a simple decoder tool currently it is able to decode texting short hand expressions, like lol, to its full phrase based off of values stored in a dictionary read in from a txt file. what i would like to do is reverse this process. I would like to take the phrase laugh out loud out of the string and replace it with its abbreviation, lol. I'm new to python so my knowledge is currently limited substantially. I do know a string in immutable so i know to convert the string to a list but my issue is how do i split the string and still keep the laugh out loud together so i can run it agaisnt the dictionary. here is my code minus the txt file any ideas or comments would be greatly appreciated.

```
class Decry:
    def __init__(self):
        self.dic_usr = 0
        self.decrypted = "none"
        self.encrypted = "none"
        self.f = 0
        self.list1 = []
        self.list2 = []
        self.list3 = []
        self.dict1 = []
        self.key1 = []
        self.key2 = []
        self.key3 = "none"

    def __buildDiction__(self):
        self.f = open("dict")
        self.build_list = self.f.read().splitlines()
        self.d_dict = {}
        for i in self.build_list:
            x = i.split(",")
            self.d_dict[x[0]] = x[1]
        return self.d_dict

    def decoder(self, usr):
        self.f = self.__buildDiction__()
        self.list1 = usr.split(" ")
        for i in self.list1:
            if i in self.f:
                self.list1[self.list1.index(i)] = self.f[i]
                self.decrypted = " ". join(self.list1)
        return self.decrypted

    def dictionary(self):
        self.f = self.__buildDiction__()
        self.list2 = []
        self.list3 = []
        self.dict1 = []
        for i in self.f:
            self.list3.append(i)
            self.list2.append(self.f[i])
        for n, g in zip(self.list3, self.list2):
            self.dict1.append(n)
            self.dict1.append(g)
            self.key1 = [self.dict1[i:i+2] for i in range(0, len(self.dict1), 2)]
            self.key2 = [" ".join(x) for x in self.key1]
            self.key3 = "\n".join(self.key2)
        return self.key3


def main():
    print("\nWelecome to quick decrypt!!!\n"
            " /~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~/")
    print("\n\nUse the number you desire.\n"
          "Proceed at your own risk:\n"
          "  1. Decrypts\n"
          "  2. Read dictionary\n"
          "  3. Add definitions to dictionary\n"
          "  4. Quit")
    deco = Decry()
    option = int(input())
    if option == 1:
        usr_input = str(input("Enter phrase to be decoded:\n"))
        f = deco.decoder(usr_input)
        print(f, "\n")
        return main()

    if option == 2:
        f = deco.dictionary()
        print(f, "\n")
        return main()

    if option == 3:
        with open("dict", "a") as txt1:
            txt1.write("\n" + str(input("Enter code followed by definition with a comma no space:\n")))
        return main()



if __name__ == "__main__":
    main()
```

Comment: This is my first Post so please be nice :) thank you

Comment: Why split the user input at all?  You can simply use [string.replace](https://docs.python.org/2/library/string.html#string.replace) to replace any phrase with any other

Comment: @fallenangel226 Welcome to Stack Overflow. Please take the [tour] and read about [ask], particularly how to create a [mcve]. Most of your question and code contain irrelevant details, which slows us down and means you haven't broken down the problem to its essence.

Comment: You shouldn't use `__double_underscore__` names that you're just making up yourself. That style of name is reserved for Python's use. You can use certain names as described in the Python documentation to customize your type (such as `__init__` setting up attributes), but for your own stuff you should just use normal names. You're also creating and using attributes *a lot* more than necessary. Just use local variables (without `self`) unless you need the value to persist between method calls.

Comment: @ Peter Wood, thank you for the advise i will keep that in mind next time i post

Comment: @ blcknght,  the class im taking in python tells us to use the double underscore for a function that is only called inside the class which is what i did. I did think The attributes were getting a little out of hand but ive only just started to learn about classes and unfortunately my teacher has us jumping around in zybooks making it really difficult to gather all the information. I've been under the impression that in a class the "self" attribute was needed for just about everything. I will go through the code and set alot of those variables to local and see where it gets me. Thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> my issue is how do i split the string and still keep the laugh out loud together so i can run it against the dictionary

Why split the string at all?  Here is a very simple solution that I hope will illustrate an alternative way to solve this without needing to split the string:

```
phrases = {'lol': 'laugh out loud', 'tbd': 'to be decided', 'btw': 'by the way'}
userString = "by the way here is a simple solution laugh out loud"
for abbr, phrase in phrases.items():
    userString = userString.replace(phrase, abbr)
print userString
```

Produces:

```
btw here is a simple solution lol
```

For larger strings you may want to consider looking at regular expressions or other more efficient techniques.

As an exercise you may want to think about how `string.replace` works - how would you implement that function?

Comment: WOW! that is a simple solution. Thank you. I thought this was going to be a lot harder but i always over complicate things so it figures :)